# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle, jdbc

```
<%@page import  ="java.sql.*" %>
<%
String DBDRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
String DBURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:8080:orcle:YK";
String DBNAME = "himyorcle";
String DBPASS = "123456";
Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
boolean flag = false;
String sql = "SELECT * FROM JOB_OPENNING";
try {
    Class.forName(DBDRIVER);
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DBURL,DBNAME,DBPASS);
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pstmt.setString(1,c_id);
    pstmt.setString(2,job_id);
    pstmt.setString(3,posinfo);
    pstmt.setString(4,no_new);
    pstmt.setString(5, title);
    rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    int i =1;
    if(rs.next()) {
        out.println(rs.getString(i));
        i++;
    }

    rs.close();
    pstmt.close();
    conn.close();

   }catch (Exception e) {
         out.println(e);
   }
   %>
```

when I do this, I have built the classpath and environment path for ojdbc6.jar and ojdbc6_g.jar. However, it still have problems for this.

I don't know why. I DO HAVE THE JAR IN THIS PROGRAM.

Comment: Try `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`. It's what Oracle says to use.

Comment: The name you use is only valid for old drivers

Comment: Ok thanks I will try